# Numbers having parseInt value = NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nan

```
   typeof 2; //number
   typeof "2"; //string
   parseInt("2");//2
   typeof Infinity; //number
   parseInt(Infinity);//NaN
   typeof NaN; //number
   parseInt(NaN);//NaN
```

are there other `Number` elements  whose parseInt value is `NaN`? If yes, list/describe them please

**UPDATES:** What doesn't make sense in JavaScript is `isNaN(NaN)` returns `true` while `typeof NaN` returns `number`

Comment: [Let's talk about Javascript](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: Always helpful to read the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): *"The value to parse. If `string` is not a string, then it is converted to one. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) works on strings, so whatever you give it, it will be converted to a string.

`Infinity => "Infinity" => NaN`

But since you asked...

```
parseInt(-Infinity); // NaN
```

Comment: really not true `alert(parseInt(UnknownVariable));` will never work or be converted into `alert(parseInt('UnknownVariable'));`

Comment: @Bellash: That's because the code throws a reference error. The variable doesn't have a value that could be passed to the function because it does not exist. However, `Infinity` is a global variable (http://es5.github.io/#x15.1) with the *value* `Infinity`. You are comparing apples with oranges. Every value passed to `parseInt` is converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

`Infinity` is a Number, try

```
isNaN(Infinity); // gives 'false' so it is a Number
```

But first parameter of `parseInt` is a string and `Infinity` already is a Number... so you can't parse it.

Comment: FWIW, `NaN` is a number too, despite its name. `typeof NaN`

Comment: And `Infinity -Infinity` gives `NaN`

Comment: Obviously `isNaN(NaN)` is `true`. That's the whole purpose of the function. But `NaN` is still a *number value*.

Comment: What doesn't make sense in JavaScript is `isNaN(NaN)` returns `true` while `typeof NaN` returns `number`

Comment: @Bellash: JavaScript implements the IEEE 754 number standard, which specifies the role of `NaN`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN: *"In computing, `NaN`, standing for not a number, is a **numeric data type** value representing an undefined or unrepresentable value, especially in floating-point calculations."* `NaN` in JavaScript is a number because that's how the standard is defined. It is a "special" number value, just like `Infinity`.